# I do a loop for 3 images swipe , but if its 4 or more my loop is broken

Tags: javascript, html

Html code are here;

```
    <div class="mySlides5">
        <img id="MainContent_img_detail" class="img-fluid news-item-img" src="assets/img/04.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>    
    <div class="mySlides5">
        <img id="MainContent_img_detail" class="img-fluid news-item-img" src="assets/img/05.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>    
    <div class="mySlides5">
        <img id="MainContent_img_detail" class="img-fluid news-item-img" src="assets/img/06.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1 , 4)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1 , 4)">&#10095;</a>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot5" onclick="currentSlide(1 , 4)"onmouseover="hoverSlide(1 , 4);" onmouseout="unhoverSlide(1 , 4);"></span>
        <span class="dot5" onclick="currentSlide(2 , 4)"onmouseover="hoverSlide(2 , 4);" onmouseout="unhoverSlide(2 , 4);"></span>
        <span class="dot5" onclick="currentSlide(3 , 4)"onmouseover="hoverSlide(3 , 4);" onmouseout="unhoverSlide(3 , 4);"></span>
    </div>
```

script code are here;

```
var slideIndex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2","mySlides3","mySlides4","mySlides5","mySlides6"];
var dots = ["dot1","dot2","dot3","dot4","dot5","dot6"];

showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);
showSlides(1, 3);
showSlides(1, 4);
showSlides(1, 5);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function currentSlide(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] = n, no);
}

function hoverSlide(n, no){
showSlides(slideIndex[no] = n, no);
}

function unhoverSlide(n, no){
showSlides(slideIndex[no] = n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName(dots[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].className = y[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";
  y[slideIndex[no]-1].className += " active";
}
```

[image: screenshot]

First 3 images is working well but 4 and above is broken
When I move the mouse over the dots, the images comes up.
I think problem is in dots because i have 3 dots but my "for" loop spining 6 times. can i break the loop in 3. Loop and can i get back to begining and second 3. Loop get out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The function `showDotSlide` is not defined here.

Comment: All ID attributes must be unique - so `MainContent_img_detail` cannot be repeated

Comment: Please add necessary CSS to support the question.

Comment: Can u see the dots on bottom of images the first dot is active on first image second dot active on second images same for three but i dont want to fourth dot, i want to repeat like the first three image dots or all of active like first dot. All of the codes working the last 2 image dots working also and next&prev buttons too